Does Ethereum ever charge an "unusual funds fee"
Trust wallet is telling me I am being charged an unusual funds fee by Ethereum for a mysterious deposit which appeared in my account.   I didn't make the deposit.

These are the steps you can follow:

Contact Trust Wallet Support: They'll explain the fee and the deposit.
Investigate: See if you recognize the sender's address.
Report a Scam (if needed): If it seems suspicious, report it to Trust Wallet.

